# Harddrive capacity error

Tags: hard-drive, memory

I initially had my Mac partitioned for Boot Camp. I re-image my computer once every year and did so today, of course knowing that my partitions will disappear.

However this time, the maximum capacity of my hard drive seems to have shrunk (see picture), and I'm not sure what's happening.

[image: Partition Tab]

[image: Numbers don't match 1]

Additional symptoms, don't know if this matters, but my computer uses 4 GB RAM running couple windows of Firefox, browsing web, but overheats really fast. 
Total RAM is 8 GB and I just had it reimaged.

Comment: First of all... why? It's not Windows, it won't fall apart or suffer from bit-rot if you don't clean install the OS every year/month/week. Secondly, what do you see when you select Partition?

Comment: when I click partition, since it's 500GB harddrive it should allow me to allocate that amount but right now it's stuck at 380GB as maximum even though it's suppose to have 500GB. 380GB was the amount I left for mac os before reimaging.

Comment: @akirakato Please add the output of `diskutil list` and `sudo gpt -r show disk0` both entered in Terminal.app to your question. Additionally add a second question regarding the 4 GB/overheat problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are hidden partitions on your drive. When you install OS X, it creates Recovery Partitions, which seem to be taking the rest of your available disk space.

You could try running Disk Utility from the OS X install DVD/USB and try to erase ALL partitions. If you don't have the installer disk, you can boot into Internet Recovery mode by holding Command + Option + R at boot chime.

Alternatively, if you have a Windows install DVD/USB, you could boot into Windows installation, press shift+F10 and use DiskPart to format the entire drive. Type the following commands into Command Prompt:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk n (n=the number of to be formatted drive)
clean
create partition primary
format fs=fat32 quick
exit
exit
```

If fat32 doesn't work, redo above steps and try 'format fs=ntfs quick' at last step.